# Ajax GET works but POST not working

Tags: ajax, jquery

I make a request with Ajax and the request works fine when I use GET. It doesn't if I use POST in my script and my Rest-Service.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/WebRestService/rest/User/deletePC',
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(antwort){
        alert("response:"+antwort);
        if (window.DOMParser)
        {
            parser=new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(antwort,"text/xml");
        }
        else // Internet Explorer
        {
            xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async="false";
            xmlDoc.loadXML(antwort);
        } 
    },
    error:function(x,e){
        if(x.status==0){
            alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
        }else if(x.status==404){
            alert('Requested URL not found.');
        }else if(x.status==500){
            alert('Internel Server Error.');
        }else if(e=='parsererror'){
            alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
        }else if(e=='timeout'){
            alert('Request Time out.');
        }else {
            alert('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText);
        }
    }
});
```

If I use POST I get an unknown error. What is the problem?

THX!

Edit: DELETE and PUt also doesn't work.
Edit2: if I use firefox Poster it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My where is you data that you are sending in your ajax request?
When you send post request you have to identify your data that you are sending.
You are missing `data` attribute of post request.

```
$.ajax({

 type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/WebRestService/rest/User/deletePC',
    data:'some data',
   dataType: "text",
  success: function(antwort){
    alert("response:"+antwort);
    },
});
```

For further reading consult [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: Well some years later this is clear, I used POST for DELETE and forgot the body...Shame on my junger me ;)